# Wildfly 8.2: component.CREATE is missing

Tags: ejb, cdi, wildfly, jboss-weld, wildfly-8

I just updated my `Wildfly-8.1.0.Final` installation to `8.2.0.Final` and deployed my WAR application and ran into deployment error.
It said

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) 
      JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "MYAPPNAME.war")]) -
      failure description: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
```

and then listed all my `EJB`s in the following manner:

```
"jboss.deployment.unit.\"MYAPPNAME.war\".component.EJBNAME.CREATE is missing [jboss.security.security-domain.java:/jaas/MYSECURITYDOMAIN]"
```

When I rolled back to `8.1.0.Final` everything worked as expected again.

All my `EJB`s are declared with `@Stateless` and there exists an empty `beans.xml` for `CDI` there aren't any other special configurations for `EJB` or `CDI` except `compontents.xml` with the following content:

```
<components>
    <component name="org.jboss.seam.core.init">
        <!-- JNDI name pattern for JBoss EJB 3.0 -->
        <property name="jndiPattern">#{ejbName}/local</property>
    </component>
</components>
```

Has anyone encountered this case and could give me a hint how to resolve it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Take a look at this Wildfly issue;

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-4116

This issue relates to;

"WAR deployment fails on missing security domain dependency"

and contains error traces in the log output that are similar in nature to the ones reported.

Specifically, constructs like;

```
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>java:/jaas/haa-portal</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

should be replaced with;

```
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>haa-portal</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

I had a similar issue and the advice in this issue rectified it for me.

Comment: While this link may provide an answer, you should include some content in your answer, in case the link ceases to be valid.

Comment: That indeed fixed my problem. If you formulate one or two short sentences, what do here, I will upvote and accept gracefully.

Comment: You save my day. Thanks